# Как отключить нажатие кнопки, если в ListView не выбран элемент

Tags: delphi

Добавил событие для ListView OnSelectItem, однако после первого выбора элемента, если кликнуть на пустое место, кнопка уже не отключается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально доступность кнопки выставлена на false. В обработчик события на фото(реагирует на нажатие по элементу) включается доступность кнопки. Однако при отмене выбора элемента, доступность кнопки не уходит в состояние false по очевидным причинам. Как можно всегда отключать кнопку, если не выбрано ни одного элемента в контроле ListView

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: а просто клик в листвью вы обработать не можете и внутри проверить, выбрано что-то или нет?

Comment: типа там `onClick(){ btn.enabled = lv.ItemIndex >= 0; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было найдено. Действие кнопки требуется занести в ActionList и назначить соответствующий обработчик .Execute в разделе events. После этого добавляем обработчик события OnUpdate для нашего ActionList, в котором прописываем следующую конструкцию: <название действия в actionlist>.enabled:=(listview.selected<>nil). Ниже приведен пример

```
procedure TFMain.ActShowReportFormExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FReportFilm.show;
  FMain.Enabled:=false;
end;

procedure TFMain.ActionList1Update(Action: TBasicAction; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  ActShowReportForm.Enabled:=(ListViewMain.Selected<>nil);
end;
```